# How do I scan away a value into nothing and not handle it?

Tags: mysql, sql, go

In Go I'm trying to write a tool to deal with the structure of MySQL tables, so I have to use a lot of queries like this one

```
show keys from`table`where`Key_name`='Primary'
```

In MySQL, I can't wrap this command with a select command and select the columns I want, so when I only want one column (in this case `Column_name`), how I do deal with the columns that I don't want? Because this query returns all of these other columns as well; `Table, Non_unique, Key_name, Seq_in_index, Column_name, Collation, Cardinality, Sub_part, Packed, Null, Index_type, Comment, Index_comment`.

In my Go code, I have lines that look like this

```
err = keysData.Scan(columnName)
```

It would be cool if I could do something like this though

```
err = keysData.Scan(_, _, _, _, columnName)
```

But that doesn't really work, getting `cannot use _ as value`

Do I have to declare throw away values for each one of these unneeded columns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA. This is more versatile than SHOW KEYS because you can select individual columns. For example:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='mytable' AND INDEX_NAME='PRIMARY'
ORDER BY SEQ_IN_INDEX
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/statistics-table.html

Comment: That is literally perfect, I found that I could scan them away into an empty interface like this `err = keysData.Scan(&x, &x, &x, &x, &columnName, &x, &x, &x, &x, &x, &x, &x, &x)` but wow that was ugly lol, plus your query ensures they're sorted correctly, so super thumbs up on that one

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, I also recommend to avoid your approach and use INFORMATION_SCHEMA as @bill-karvin suggested.

But to strictly reply to your question, you could use a dummy [`sql.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner) that always succeed, but does nothing:

```
type dummyScanner struct{}

func (dummyScanner) Scan(v interface{}) error {
    return nil
}

var skip dummyScanner

err = keysData.Scan(skip, skip, skip, skip, columnName, skip, skip, skip, skip, skip, skip, skip, skip)
```